# What happens to bitcoin transactions that are unconfirmed during the hard fork?

Tags: blockchain-fork

So I've just moved my bitcoins out of Coinbase into my own wallet in anticipation of the hard fork as they will only support BTC (and not BCC) afterwards.

It's been about 6-7 hours and it still is in Pending. On their help site(https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/593836), there is a message saying "Partially Degraded Service: In advance of the upcoming potential hard fork, we are processing a large volume of outgoing Bitcoin transactions. Recent or new outgoing BTC transactions may be delayed by up to 12+ hours as we process this backlog."

So I'm hoping that 3 days is enough to get my transaction but I'm wondering, at the time of the hard fork, what will happen to the transactions that are midway though? Would it be different if the transaction has had no confirmations vs if it already has a few confirmations but just not the 6 for it to be fully confirmed?

Will they end up in the new wallet address for both the BCC and BTC network? Will they end up in the new wallet address for only BTC and BCC will still be in the old address?

Answer (score 1):

If the transactions are still unconfirmed after the hard fork has occurred, you will only receive the coins on your Bitcoin wallet, not the Bitcoin Cash wallet. In that case, Coinbase still holds all of your Bitcoin Cash coins.

Comment: So if we keep both source and destination private keys of an unconfirmed transaction, no risk to lose fork tokens, right?

Comment: If you have the private keys, you cannot lose any coins at all.